# How to correct for FIlter function error in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

I am trying to filter data in a dataframe using `filter()` function but I am getting an error:

```
ios_fb_result1 <- ios_fb_result %>%
  filter(date(datecol)>='2021-10-01' & date(datecol) < '2021-12-23')

Error: Problem with filter()` input `..1.
ℹ Input `..1` is date(datecol) == "2021-10-01".
✖ unused argument (datecol)
```

dput(head(ios_fb_result))

```
structure(list(datecol = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2021-10-01", 
"2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", 
"2021-10-07", "2021-10-08", "2021-10-09", "2021-10-10", "2021-10-11", 
"2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-14", "2021-10-15", "2021-10-16", 
"2021-10-17", "2021-10-18", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-20", "2021-10-21", 
"2021-10-22", "2021-10-23", "2021-10-24", "2021-10-25", "2021-10-26", 
"2021-10-27", "2021-10-28", "2021-10-29", "2021-10-30", "2021-10-31", 
"2021-11-01", "2021-11-02", "2021-11-03", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-05", 
"2021-11-06", "2021-11-07", "2021-11-08", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", 
"2021-11-11", "2021-11-12", "2021-11-13", "2021-11-14", "2021-11-15", 
"2021-11-16", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-18", "2021-11-19", "2021-11-20", 
"2021-11-21", "2021-11-22", "2021-11-23", "2021-11-24", "2021-11-25", 
"2021-11-26", "2021-11-27", "2021-11-28", "2021-11-29", "2021-11-30", 
"2021-12-01", "2021-12-02", "2021-12-03", "2021-12-04", "2021-12-05", 
"2021-12-06", "2021-12-07", "2021-12-08", "2021-12-09", "2021-12-10", 
"2021-12-11", "2021-12-12", "2021-12-13", "2021-12-14", "2021-12-15", 
"2021-12-16", "2021-12-17", "2021-12-18", "2021-12-19", "2021-12-20", 
"2021-12-21", "2021-12-22", "2021-12-23", "2021-12-24", "2021-12-25", 
"2021-12-26", "2021-12-27", "2021-12-28", "2021-12-29", "2021-12-30", 
"2021-12-31", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", 
"2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", 
"2022-01-10"), class = "factor"), response = c(1124, 965, 1030, 
1324, 1377, 2827), cum.response = c(1124, 2089, 3119, 4443, 5820, 
8647), point.pred = c(1715.94529277584, 1609.33717991531, 1734.44307036591, 
1715.59696513439, 1644.54171869339, 2151.33940525175)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post sample data, edit the question with the output of `dput(head(ios_fb_result))`.

Comment: ```filter()``` is used in multiple packages, I think you are trying to use dplyr here, so make sure dplyr is loaded in case it's using a different package like stats.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, added a pic for sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Is `date` from lubridate? It's important to list what packages you're using. Adding to what @Silentdevildoll said, it looks like you tried to call `filter` without either loading `dplyr` or explicitly naming it (`dplyr::filter`), which instead called a different function with the same name but different arguments (presumably `stats::filter`). Not loading the packages you're trying to use makes this a non-reproducible problem. In addition to that, you'll have trouble trying to convert a factor to a date

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have mixed data types. The `datacol` variable is of type 'factor' rather than of type 'date'. You can see this in the `class = "factor"`  part of the `dput`:

```r
structure(list(datecol = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2021-10-01", 
...
"2022-01-10"), class = "factor"
...
```

For your comparison (`date(datecol)>='2021-10-01'`) it looks like you are trying to convert the `datacol` column to a date type (though note the right-hand-side is a string).

In R the functions to convert data types all start with `as.`. So you are probably looking for `as.Date` or `as.character` rather than just `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Like it's said in [Simon.S.A.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687578/8245406), your date column is of class `"factor"`. This can be seen with any of

```
str(ios_fb_result)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ datecol     : Factor w/ 102 levels "2021-10-01","2021-10-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
# $ response    : num  1124 965 1030 1324 1377 ...
# $ cum.response: num  1124 2089 3119 4443 5820 ...
# $ point.pred  : num  1716 1609 1734 1716 1645 ...

class(ios_fb_result$datecol)
#[1] "factor"
```

So all you have to do is to coerce to class `"Date"` in the pipe. And remove the call to `date()`.

```
library(dplyr)

ios_fb_result1 <- ios_fb_result %>%
  mutate(datecol = as.Date(as.character(datecol))) %>%
  filter(datecol >= '2021-10-01' & datecol < '2021-12-23')
```